# Dimension of the socle of the first local cohomology module

Tags: reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $M$ be a graded $\mathbb{C}[z_0,\dots,z_n]$-module. Using local duality one can show that
$$
\dim_\mathbb{C} (\text{soc} H_\mathfrak{m}^1(M))_k = \beta_{n,k+n+1}(M).
$$
Here $H_\mathfrak{m}^1(M)$ denotes the first local cohomology module of $M$ with respect to the ideal $\mathfrak{m} = (z_0,\dots,z_n) \subset \mathbb{C}[z_0,\dots,z_n]$, and $\beta_{i,j}(M)$ denotes the graded Betti numbers of $M$.

Has this formula appeared in print somwhere? The closest thing I could find was in https://arxiv.org/pdf/0809.1458.pdf, where is says on page 17 that *"...the socle of the first nonzero local cohomology precisely reflects the top Betti numbers."*

**Edit:** I also found an ungraded version of the formula in Theorem 12.4 in *Combinatorics and Commutative Algebra* by Stanley.

Comment: I would check the Brodmann-Sharp book on Local Cohomology.